# How to return a static class instance in c#

Tags: c#, singleton

I would like to get an instance of a static class, but I can’t seem to do this without implementing a singleton wrapper on a non-static class– is this possible, or am I missing something?

```
public class MyInstanceTester
 {
    public MyInstanceTester()
    {
        //this is how i get a reference to a singleton now
        MyClass instance1 = MyClass.Instance();
        //this is what is would like to do (if only the compiler would let me)
        MyStaticClass instance2 = MyStaticClass.Instance();
    }
}


public class MyClass
{
    private static MyClass _myInstance;

    static MyClass()
    {
        _myInstance = new MyClass();
    }


    public static MyClass Instance()
    {
        return _myInstance;
    }

}

public static class MyStaticClass
{
    public static MyStaticClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can get an instance of a static class.  I think that is the point of static class.  Is it not?

Comment: Yes you miss something. "this" has no meaning in a static method. Or to put it in other words: "this" is a null reference in static methods. The compiler does rightfully save you from trying to return null references.

Comment: @AloisKraus The variable `this` does not exists in this context because its always the first argument of a method and the first argument of a static method is used for "user"-arguments.

Comment: The get method of MyStaticClass Instance is static where he tries to return this. THIS will not work. The compiler will complain about this one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no such thing as an instance of a static class. The singleton pattern simply returns the same instance of a class to repeated requests.

You may be getting confused by:

```
private static MyClass _myInstance;
```

This simply means that there will be a single instance of that particular object among all objects instantiated of the type that have _myInstance as a member.

A few notes:

- The `this` keyword is not valid in a static member
- If you have a static class then all members have to be static and so `this` will never be valid
- A Singleton class cannot be a static class
- Singletons declare a single static member to help ensure that only a single instance of that class exists
- Note that a static reference to an object does not make the object static. Only the reference is static

**Further reading:** Jon Skeet has an excellent write up on implemeting [Singletons in C# In Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx). I would suggest reading and studying this article until you grok it. It is quite good.

Comment: thanks, you have answered the first part of my question perfectly: "There is no such thing as an instance of a static class".  But to add some more context (see my comments on @felix-k response). What i am trying to achieve is: I have a bunch of static methods in a static class, i want to return a reference to these as an object - what's the best way to do that?

Comment: If you have a static class you reference it directly. References to static classes are not really returned they are accessed directly. I think all you're really looking for is a static class. Forget the Singleton pattern and use a static class like this: `var result = MyStaticClass.SomeStaticFunction();`

Comment: there in lies the issue, i cannot access it directly, i have to implement this interface [IScriptedContentFragmentExtension](http://telligent.com/community/developers/w/developer6/creating-new-widget-extensions.aspx) to pass my object to an [NVelocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html) template (similar to razor) as an object reference, the methods are then called from the object in the NVelocity template.

Comment: OK. A static class cannot implement an interface. It is not allowed. So the singleton pattern is fine here. What's the problem with your first example then? `MyClass instance1 = MyClass.Instance();`

Comment: i don't have a problem with my original MyClass `instance1 = MyClass.Instance()` solution, i just thought i might be missing a trick and there was a simple way to get a reference to a static class. Clearly i'm not, as you have pointed out "There is no such thing as an instance of a static class", thanks for the input

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason to return a `instance to a static class` ( If the class is static there is no instance ).

You can access the class from everywhere, why returning a `instance` to it? I can't imagine any reason to do this.

#### Static class usage

To use a static class just write it like below:

```
MyStaticClass.MyMethod();
Int32 callCount = MyStaticClass.CallCount;
```

As you can see it doesn't even make sense to declare a variable because this would just look like this:

```
MyStaticClass msc = MyStaticClass.Instance();
msc.MyMethod();
Int32 callCount = msc.CallCount;
```

If you want to have a shorter name you just can use:

```
 using MSC = MyNamespace.MyStaticClass;
```

Comment: hi @felix-k the reason for this is i am implementing an interface that returns an object, I want that object to be a reference to an existing static utility  class that i have: `public object InerfaceProperty { get { return MyStaticUtilityClass.Instance ; } }`

Comment: @PeteN If i understand your correctly this is my answer: You can't implement a interface on a static type, so use the singletone-pattern to archive what you need.

Comment: hi @felix-k , not sure you quite understand, nearly though, the interface is not mine, from a third party i have no control over it, it is being implemented on a non-static class, but one of the interface properties returns an object, i want that to return a reference to my static utility class (so as to expose it's methods to an NVelocity template) - so a slightly different scenario, although i imagine the answer is the same :)

Comment: @PeteN As mentioned above, you simply can't return a reference to your static class, the only way to archive this is to make it a singletone. Maybe you could update your answer with more information for other readers.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments I assume your solution would be:

Make your class non-static. (Just keep the methods static.)

Comment: static methods can be only called by class name and u can't call them by the object name

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology is wrong. Please read the [MSDN article on the static keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

> A static member cannot be referenced through an instance. Instead, it
>   is referenced through the type name.

A [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is a class that only allows a single instance of itself. A common implimentation of this in C# is:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private MyClass _value = null;

    public MyClass Value {
        get { return _value ?? (_value = new MyClass()); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The major problem is here:

```
public static class MyStaticClass 
{     
    public static MyStaticClass Instance
    {         
         get
             {             
                  return this; //compile time error!
             }
    }
}
```

`this` refers to an instance of a class which does not make sense in a static class as there can be no instance of one. This by itself should make you realize that there is a fundamental error in what you are asking: "I would like to get an instance of a static class". You can not return an instance of a static class as a static class by definition can not be instantiated.

The singleton pattern just makes sure that you always return the *same* instance of a class. But said class can never be static.