# C# - Static types cannot be used as return types

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I looked through SO for some answers but i couldn't find an explanation for the error my compiler complains about. I'm creating a CRUD app and here are a few lines of code.

```
public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

public static implicit operator AppContext(AppDbContext v)
```

Comment: You have an operator that purports to be able to convert an instance of `AppDbContext` into an instance of `AppContext`. But [`AppContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) is static. There cannot be *any* instances of that class.

Answer (score -2):

Well non-static classes are instances created at the runtime and you can return instances of classes or types. When static there are no such thing as instances. Thats why its **static**

[How to return a static class instance in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514729/how-to-return-a-static-class-instance-in-c-sharp)